How calculate the values of resistance and capacitor for a 7805 regulator circuit?

I would like to know how to calculate the values of Rs and Cout in this circuit.

Can you provide a link to where you found this circuit?

This looks like three different schematics pasted together.

the resistor has no function other than slightly warming the room and reducing the quality of regulation.

You have a regulator whose output voltage should be 5 V (within the tolerances specified for it, but let's stick with 5 V). The circuit shows a resistor \$R_S\$ in series with the output, and a capacitor \$C_{OUT}\$ to ground after the resistor. It also indicates \$I = 200 mA\$ and \$V_{OUT} = 5 V\$. So for the resistor just calculate the resistance that would give you 5 V out from a 5 V source with 200 mA current through it (there's a useful clue later).
As for the capacitor, it could be pretty much any value, there's no way to tell from the given circuit.
Now, that's based on one interpretation of the question and schematic. If instead the schematic is suggesting that there's a resistance you could put on the output of the regulator that would limit the current to 200 mA while still supplying 5 V to a load, then there is no correct answer as this is not how a voltage regulator works. If you simply used Ohm's Law and divided 5 V by 200 mA you'd get 25Ω, but then you'd have no voltage at the output as it would all drop across the resistor (the load would have to be shorted). Any resistance other than zero Ohms would drop voltage so you couldn't get \$V_{OUT} = 5 V\$, you would get \$V_{OUT} = 5 V - (I_{OUT}\times R_S)\$. And again, there's not enough information to determine the capacitor value.
Now, if what you're really asking is how to build a 7805 regulator circuit the resistor wouldn't be needed at all as it would be detrimental to the circuit, and the capacitor would be optional. When a capacitor is used on the output it's generally something like 100 nF and sometimes a second capacitor is added, maybe 1 uF to 100 uF.
